# Javascript : search a tag by a value in a attribute to change its classname

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, tags

I have a html code where I want to find a tag that contains a value in one of its attributes.

Here is the html code :

```
<select name="client" class="select form-select" id="id_client" style="display : none "> 
    <option value="1109">Charles</option> 
    <option value="1108">Fred</option> 
    <option value="1107">Lionel</option> 
    <option value="1106">Robert</option> 
    <option value="1105">Mike</option>
</select>
<div class="dropdown dselect-wrapper select">
    <button class="form-select " data-dselect-text="Charles" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Charles
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <input onkeydown="return event.key !== 'Enter'" onkeyup="dselectSearch(event, this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select', false)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autofocus="">
        <div class="dselect-items" style="max-height:360px;overflow:auto">
          <button class="dropdown-item active" data-dselect-value="1109" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Charles</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1108" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Fred</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1107" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Lionel</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1106" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Robert</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" data-dselect-value="1105" type="button" onclick="dselectUpdate(this, 'dselect-wrapper', 'form-select')">Mike</button>
        </div>
        <div class="dselect-no-results d-none">No results found</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

On click on a button, I get and id value by `<button onclick="myFunc(this.id)"  id="1106">Select client</button>`. So I get the ID value of 1106.

```
function myFunc(clicked_id){
    };
```

I want to find the tag in the html code above that contains the attribute `data-dselect-value="1106"` with the id value that is the same. Then change its className from `class="dropdown-item"` to `class="dropdown-item active"`.

I do not see how to do that.

Thank you

Comment: `document.querySelector('[data-dselect-value="1106"])` wil select the first elemnt with that data-attribute and value. The  big advantage of querySelector and querySelectorAll is that you can address elements the same way as in CSS (incl. pseudo-selectors)

Comment: you can use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with a [css attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like: `*[data-dselect-value=1106]` and then through the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property change its class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
function myFunc(clicked_id){
    var elem = document.querySelector('[data-dselect-value="'+clicked_id+'"]');
    elem.classList.add('active');   
};
```

Comment: instead of using a + operator you could use backticks and include a variable inside that string with `${variable}`

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector('[data-dselect-value="1106"]')`